# Implementation of a Recursive Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm currently working with mssql server manager and I encountered a problem.

I need to implement a recursive relationship and I don't seem to get it to work in such a way that it doesn't have redundancy.

The problem occurs on the following table:
I got a table: 'Order',
An order can have multiple 'Suborder'

Now, I have no idea how to implement this in such a way in mssql that it doesn't have redundancy.

Edit:
Redundancy means that the database saves data multiple times.

In this case that would mean. The main order would be saved multiple times into the database because there are multiple suborders attached to it.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO order (order_id, order_name, suborder) VALUES (1, Intel, Network);
INSERT INTO order (order_id, order_name, suborder) VALUES (1, Intel, Finance);
INSERT INTO order (order_id, order_name, suborder) VALUES (1, Intel, Datamodel);
INSERT INTO order (order_id, order_name, suborder) VALUES (2, AMD, null);
INSERT INTO order (order_id, order_name, suborder) VALUES (3, NMI, null);
```

In this way, it saves order_id and order_name multiple times, and that's just what *not* should happen.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "reduncancy". Showing sample data and queries would help even more. (please edit the *question* do not try and show code in comments).

Comment: What means redundancy? Otherwise I can see one table `Order` and FK relationship into itself - and maybe some flag to indicate top-level order, if required.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please have read of this [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to be more proper.

Comment: In order table, you can save main/common things of order like customer name, address, ph no etc, while for suborder you can use suborder detail with main order reference id to map order with suborder. are you able to understand ? So do not have any redundant data with managing both tables

Comment: What is difference between `Order` and `Suborder`?

Comment: "A main order would be saved multiple times into the database because there's multiple suborders attached to it". That's not how parent/child works. There's _one_ parent order record saved with an id of 7 for example. Then you save multiple children records whose "parent key" is 7. There is no reason to save multiple parent records. You're misunderstanding something fundamental. If you took the time to explain it properly you would probably solve it yourself.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that's exactly my problem. I do not know how to implement the parent and child structure.

Comment: show us your table design. The example you posted looks like a very bad design

Comment: @GuidoG this is only part of the table to show the problem. And I know it's a bad design, that's why i ask the question. The question is literaly how to fix this design in such a way it doesnt save the same data multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need much more tables for master child relation
Look up the term `Normalization` and read more about it

for example

```
 table Client (ClientID, Name, Addres, ...)

 table Article (ArticleID, Name, Stock, ...)

 table Order (OrderID, ClientID, DeliveryAddress, ...)

 table SubOrder (SubOrderID, OrderID, ArticleID, Quantity, ...)
```

In this design the order data is only saved once, and each SubOrder only saves the OrderID to maintain its relation to order.
Also data about the client and Article is only save once, only ID's are save multiple times

I have used key names like `ClientID` and `ArticleID` in this example, you will find that often the name `ID` is used instead. This was just to make the relation in the example more clear